# Can't connect to docker-machine container on digitalocean

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean, docker-machine

I've got a java servlet container running in edge_web_1 which I can access on port 8080 and I can't access 80 or 443 on edge_nginx_1. Any ideas?

```
# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
99c26fe2117e        nginx:1             "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp   edge_nginx_1
571ef4787dbc        edge_web            "/tmp/entrypoint.sh"     27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp                     edge_web_1
7f0c15522a70        mongo:3             "/entrypoint.sh mo..."   58 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       27017/tcp                                  edge_db_1
```

From the docker host:

```
# curl localhost:8080
{"code":404,"message":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}
```

(The json response means I'm through to the servlet container, a 404 is fine for this).

```
# curl localhost:80
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

I get the same for 443. I've tried using 18080 instead of 80 in case it was something to do with privileged ports. The host is created using docker-machine with the digitalocean driver. The containers are configured with docker-compose and it all works both locally and with the virtualbox driver.

Curiously (to me) on virtualbox docker-machine set things up to run as the docker user, on digitalocean it seems to run as the root user. The iptables rules are very different too, but the digitalocean ones look no different for 80 than 8080.

```
# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.4           tcp dpt:8080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

ETA:

Seems to be related to the digitalocean docker-machine instance not handling volumes. Looking at the nginx container it doesn't contain the files from the volumes. I can reproduce it with just these:

docker-compose.yml

```
nginx:
  image: nginx:1
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./testconf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    - ./testhtml:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

testconf/nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen        80;
  server_name _;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @proxy;
  }
}
```

testhtml/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's expected behaviour that this would work locally, to virtualbox and then not when deploying to DO or I'd guess EC2.

Seems a bit rubbish, not to mention unexpected, to me.

https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/3982